# Way to loop from the middle of the while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 inputs to type and I want to loop through them if the user would enter incorrect input. What I did is I set while True and then try and except and then continue. However in case of second input if the input is wrong then whole loop is repeated from the start - that is from the first input. I would like it to be repeated from the second input. The only thing that I can think of is to put break in the code after first correct input and then set another while True for the second input. What are better ways to do this?

```
while True:
    try:
        a = int(input("Type positive integer: "))
    except ValueError:
        print(" Enter a positive NUMBER!")
        continue
    if a <= 0:
        print("Input can't be 0 or negative!")
        continue
    else:
        try:
            b = int(input("Type second positive integer: "))
        except ValueError:
                print(" Enter a positive NUMBER!")
                continue
        if b <= 0:
            print("Input can't be 0 or negative!")
            continue
        else:
            break
```

Comment: There is no better way to do that.

Comment: You don't need the first `else:` clause because you are breaking out of the loop. Remove `else:` and unindent the rest would make it a little more readable.

Comment: You could save them in a tuple, using the same loop for both variables, by increasing the tuple index from 0 to 1 once the first number was entered correctly.

Comment: You could put your while loop inside a for loop. This would remove quite a bit of duplicated code.

Comment: Paul Panzer could you give an example of that for loop. Specifically what would be an iterator in that loop?

Comment: @user9546355 use your message as the iterator for the loop, as this is the only difference between the 2 inputs - see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your condition is the same for each loop, you could try storing the try-except part as a function which returns the value (or a bool indicating success or failure with a parameter for the value), running the lambda in a for loop for each input you require, storing the result in a list and then getting what you need out as a tuple.

E.g.

```
def try_get_number_input():
    try:
        value = int(input("Type positive integer: "))
    except ValueError:
        print(" Enter a positive NUMBER!")
        return False, 0
    if value <= 0:
        print("Input can't be 0 or negative!")
        return False, 0

    return True, value


# We require 2 inputs from the user
required_inputs = 2
received_inputs = []
for num in range(0, required_inputs):
    values = try_get_number_input()
    while not values[0]:
        values = try_get_number_input()

    received_inputs.append(values[1])
```

This ensures that the code is DRY (doesn't repeat itself) and is easily changeable (if you require 3 inputs instead, you can easily change it rather than having to add another branch of your while loop)

Answer (score 0):

```
def getNumber(second=False):
    while True:
        try:
            if second:
                number = int(input("Type second positive integer: "))
            else:
                number = int(input("Type positive integer: "))
        except ValueError:
            print(" Enter a positive NUMBER!")
            continue
        if number <= 0:
            print("Input can't be 0 or negative!")
            continue
        return number

a, b =  getNumber(second=False),  getNumber(second=True)
print(a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked what a `for` loop would look like, here's one example:

```
vals = []
for msg in ['', 'second ']:
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input(f"Type {msg}positive integer: "))            # PY3.6
            # n = int(input("Type {}positive integer: ").format(msg))) # <=PY3.5
        except ValueError:
            print(" Enter a positive NUMBER!")
            continue
        if n <= 0:
            print("Input can't be 0 or negative!")
            continue
        vals.append(n)
        break
a, b = vals
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use decorator for retry logic and single function to read int value

```
def retry(func):
    def wrapper(msg):
        while True:
            try:
                return func(msg)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
    return wrapper

@retry
def read_int(msg):
    try:
        a = int(input(msg))
    except:
        raise ValueError('Invalid Number')
    else:
        if a < 0:
            raise ValueError('Number should be positive')
    return a


a = read_int('type valid positive number: ')
b = read_int('type other valid positive number: ')
print(a, b)
```